# Why does this code block log to the console in an unexpected order?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm extremely confused why the following code returns what it does when I write it using both promise chaining and async/await syntax:

```js
function log() {
  console.log("Hello from inside second await")
}

async function test() {
  await console.log("Hello from first await");
  await setTimeout(log, 1000);
  await console.log("Hello from third await");
}

test();
console.log('Where does this occur?')
```

I thought the `await` keyword made the code asynchronous. Why is the first await printing to the console instantly ahead of the `console.log` in the main thread? Additionally, why is the second await occurring after the third? Isn't the purpose of `await` to make sure that important data for future functions exists before they're executed? This makes no sense to me, help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Asynchronous" doesn't mean "after everything else in the script".

Comment: `await` makes only sense if the function is returning an `Promise`. Nothing of them above is returning an promise, so its useless. ´setTimeout´ returns an number back. In the docs, they use in almost every example promises https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: `I thought the await keyword made the code asynchronous` - this is not true and has never been true. It does not **make** anything asynchronous, however if something **is already** asynchronous **AND** returns a `Promise` it will pause the execution of the next line until the Promise is resolved

Comment: The `async` keyword means that the function is guarenteed to return a Promise.  If you return a non-promise (via `return` or using an `await`), it will be wrapped into a resolved Promise.  The code is not async, but the return value might represent a future value (pending Promise).  `setTimeout` doesn't return a Promise, but a timer identifier.  `await` on this just returns a resolved Promise for the number, without waiting for the timeout.

Comment: I see, the examples only used promises with asynchronous code and I mistakenly attributed this behavior to the `await` keyword. Thanks to everyone who actually answered instead of going after a new programmer.

Answer (score -1):

The async function means it will be to executed somtime. More from javascript async functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Nope.  It means that the function returns a Promise, one that might be already resolved.  Effectively it is a generator function that produces a Promise every time if encounters an await.  If you return a non-Promise, it's wrapped into a resolved promise.  It's just packaging, and doesn't actually cause asynchronous behaviour.

Comment: @Dave Meehan You are right, I tought the code which called after the async function can be executed at the middle.